# Getting incorrect value for timestamp column with MySQL 8 server using mysql-connector-java jdbc driver 8.0.18

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

We have migrated our application from MySQL 5.1.6 to MySQL 8.0.16

While retrieving timestamp column from MySQL 8 server using mysql-connector-java jdbc driver (version 8.0.18, 8.0.19), we are getting incorrect value for the date value which is in daylight saving time (DST).

**Both our server hosting java application & MySQL database are in EST.**

Here, we have a column `created_date` having type datetime. It has value '2020-03-17 23:01:54' for a specific row. While retrieving same data through JDBC as:

```
Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp("created_date");
```

we are getting value as 2020-03-18 00:01:54.0 
i.e. DST is getting applied.

There is a known bug in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-known-issues-limitations.html

It suggest to use add additional parameter in jdbc url serverTimezone=UTC. But we can't use UTC because we want to use deployment specific timezone in our application/database.

**Note: We were not facing this issue with MySQL 5.1.**

Additional update:
While inserting data into database, If I use jdbc url with parameter serverTimezone=UTC, then while retrieving timestamp column I get correct value.

So it seems with serverTimezone=UTC, JDBC driver is not applying DST while storing timestamp in database. So workaround suggested  (i.e. serverTimezone=UTC) seems to be working.

But If I insert data using Load Data Local file command using JDBC url containing serverTimezone=UTC i.e.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.....")
```

it seems serverTimezone=UTC flag is getting ignored & data is getting stored with DST applied timestamp value. So while retrieving timestamp, we are getting incorrect value.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: It's not really a solution to your problem but I would recommend storing the values in a UTC timezone and then converting them to the timezone which your server is in. This way you always now how the time is stored in the DB and this is not location dependent and you let the 'client' or application itself handle the conversion, preventing bugs like this

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it by installing the new version (8.0.20) of Connector/J 8 driver:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-20.html